# That sound thats used in the drop of most melodic dubstep songs

Tags: ableton-live

I am new to music production, and I've been using Ableton for about 2 months now.

I was wondering if I could recreate the sound used in most melodic dubstep drops, here are some examples:

[Just A Gent ft. R O Z E S - Limelight](https://youtu.be/Wi2uU3kTQ24?t=1m4s)

[Birdy - Skinny Love (Vanic Remix)](https://youtu.be/37DIzz5Q2bM?t=3m12s)

[Juventa ft. Kelly Sweet - Superhuman (Culture Code Remix)](https://youtu.be/tofdXrnTVoE?t=3m25s)

I saw it in an FLP file once, when I used FL Studio, and it was made with `Harmor`.

If anyone has a tutorial I could follow, or even a preset for a VST, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you happen to provide timestamps of these melodic dubstep drops?

Comment: The YouTube links have timestamps :) Just need to click them

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a big chord played with a few detuned saws, you should be able to get the sound in any synth that you have available.

Here's a tutorial that's using Serum (

).

If you're using Massive a dimension expander will probably help to fill out the sound.